# Tracking the time on each Cell like Hours App

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

I have a `UITableViewCell` with some buttons that have time values like the hours app. I would like to track the time on each cell whenever I click on the button related to that cell like the hours app does - as shown in the screen shot below.

I already know how deal with timers: The function below is used to update the time on a general label :

```
var startTime = TimeInterval()
var timer : Timer?


func updateTime() {

        let currentTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

        //Find the difference between current time and start time.

        var elapsedTime: TimeInterval = currentTime - startTime

        //calculate the minutes in elapsed time.
        let minutes = UInt8(elapsedTime / 60.0)

        elapsedTime -= (TimeInterval(minutes) * 60)

        //calculate the seconds in elapsed time.
        let seconds = UInt8(elapsedTime)

        elapsedTime -= TimeInterval(seconds)

        //add the leading zero for minutes, seconds and millseconds and store them as string constants

        let strMinutes = String(format: "%02d", minutes)
        let strSeconds = String(format: "%02d", seconds)

        //concatenate minuets, seconds and milliseconds as assign it to the UILabel

        self.timeLabel?.text = "\(strMinutes):\(strSeconds)"
        //labelShake(labelToAnimate: self.timeLabel!, bounceVelocity: 5.0, springBouncinessEffect: 8.0)

    }
```

I can put the following code in `ViewDidLoad` to start the timer:

```
        timer = Timer()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.01, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTime), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        startTime = NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
```

For tapping a button in a cell, I add a tag on the cell's button to track the cell that I tapped on as shown below

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        //...
        cell.timerViewButton.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.timerViewButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startTimerForCell), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        //...

       return cell

}
```

// I can track the button clicked here.

```
func startTimerForCell(sender : UIButton) {


        print("SelectedCell \(sender.tag)")


    }
```

Can anyone help with how can I change the button title on the cell clicked to the do the counting and potential stopping the timer when I click on the button

[image]

Comment: I don't think it as the convenient way to do so, as per my thinking you should take scrollView and label to implement this. Because in tablecell the cell value can be changed only by reloading table, and reloading table by means of timer is not advisable.

Comment: @Janmenjaya I don't follow what you mean? Do you mean the entire view should be built with a scrollView and Labels instead of a Tableview?

Comment: Yes, because if I am not wrong, you want to display timer like stop watch, so for that you have taken NSTimer. suppose you set timer to 1 second. Then to update the cell in table view you need to call reload data, so in every second you need to call reload data to update the label, so as to display a running time text. And to reload tale after each second is not convenient. rather you can take scrollView and label, and update that particular label based on some tag. I hope i have justified my answer.

Comment: You definitely have and it makes sense. I will try the answer below and see if that works otherwise a scrollView it is.

Comment: I wonder how the guys at Hours did it. It looks like they cracked the problem quite elegantly since it's using a TableView from the looks of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, your problem is want to track each timer states. Just keep in mind that `UITableViewCell` is reusable and it will keep change when you scroll or view it.

Normally I will use array to easily keep track all those states or values in cell.

So, in your controller will have class variables probably as below

```
struct Timer {
    let start = false
    let seconds = 0
    // can have more properties as your need
}

var timers = [Timer]()
```

Then, in your start function `startTimerForCell` will keep monitor those array.

```
func startTimerForCell(sender : UIButton) {
    let timer = timers[sender.tag]
    if timer.start {
        // stop the timer
        timers[sender.tag].start = false
    }
    else {
        // stop the timer
        timers[sender.tag].start = true
    }
}
```

Comment: That certainly makes sense as a way to keep track of the timer starting or stopping - I will give it a shot. How would you pass the time value to the button's titleLabel that's clicked? That's the rather tricky part I can't seem to get my head around. I am used to doing this using the cellForRowAtIndexPath function.

Comment: you can do that on cell for row just use `let timer = timers[indexPath.row]` then set your button title to `timer.start == true ? "Stop" : "Start"`

Comment: you could also update your timer lable that (0:00) using the `second` property then properly reload your cell, just divide and find reminder by 60

Comment: I see.. I'll give it a shot and get back to you. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity will the button reload the title without having to reload the TableView to update it?

Comment: You can reload by indexpaths or the whole tsblrview to update the value